# MySQL group by affecting other group

Tags: mysql

I've got a `SUM(value)` which calculates the votes for each `idea`, but this gets affected by the amount of `tag`s each idea can have.

For example,

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  title,
  description,
  COALESCE(SUM(case when value > 0 then value end),0) votes_up,
  COALESCE(SUM(case when value < 0 then value end),0) votes_down,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.name) AS 'tags',
FROM ideas
LEFT JOIN votes    ON ideas.id        = votes.idea_id
LEFT JOIN tags_rel ON ideas.id        = tags_rel.idea_id
LEFT JOIN tags     ON tags_rel.tag_id = tags.id
GROUP BY ideas.id
```

So if there are more than one `tags.name`, then the `SUM()` gets multiplied by the number of `tags.name`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Every other DBMS would reject that statement. Read this http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html and this http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/ to understand what is wrong with your `group by` usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your `SUM` affected with `tags`, you should not **include** `tags` into your `SUM` query.

I think you can split your query into 2 part (**query inside a query**) . First to SUM **without** ideas , then JOIN ideas data for result base on first part

Something would like (sorry but I did not test my query yet but the idea is like that):

```
SELECT 
  t.id, 
  t.title,
  t.description,
  t.votes_up,
  t.votes_down,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.name) AS 'tags',

FROM
(
  SELECT 
    id, 
    title,
    description,
    COALESCE(SUM(case when value > 0 then value end),0) votes_up,
    COALESCE(SUM(case when value < 0 then value end),0) votes_down,
  FROM ideas
  LEFT JOIN votes    ON ideas.id        = votes.idea_id
  GROUP BY ideas.id
) as t
LEFT JOIN tags_rel ON t.id        = tags_rel.idea_id
LEFT JOIN tags     ON tags_rel.tag_id = tags.id
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  ideas.id, 
  title,
  description,
  COALESCE(SUM(case when value > 0 then value end),0)*t2.cnt votes_up,
  COALESCE(SUM(case when value < 0 then value end),0)*t2.cnt votes_down,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.name) AS 'tags'
FROM ideas
LEFT JOIN votes    ON ideas.id        = votes.idea_id
LEFT JOIN tags_rel ON ideas.id        = tags_rel.idea_id
LEFT JOIN tags     ON tags_rel.tag_id = tags.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT idea_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
            FROM tags_rel 
           GROUP BY tags_rel.idea_id) t2 ON ideas.id = t2.idea_id
GROUP BY ideas.id
```

See [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e02df1/14/0)

EDIT :

With the tags count column included in the result :

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e02df1/16/0)**:

```
| ID |  TITLE | DESCRIPTION | VOTES_UP | VOTES_DOWN |                    TAGS | TAGS_COUNT |
|----|--------|-------------|----------|------------|-------------------------|------------|
|  1 | TITLE1 |       DESC1 |       12 |         -4 |             tags1,tags2 |          2 |
|  2 | TITLE2 |       DESC2 |       18 |          0 |       tags4,tags5,tags3 |          3 |
|  3 | TITLE3 |       DESC3 |        0 |        -16 | tags9,tags7,tags8,tags6 |          4 |
|  4 | TITLE4 |       DESC4 |        1 |          0 |                  tags10 |          1 |
```

Comment: May be the `*t2.cnt` is not where you want :)

Comment: Your votes are still getting multiplied by the amount of tags. For example, in your `idea.id = 3`, you've only got one `-1` vote, but the data shows `-16`

Comment: May be it's my test data or another part of your logic but look at this [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e02df1/16/0) and you will see that `*t2.cnt` contain the right count of tags. So just add `LEFT JOIN (SELECT idea_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
            FROM tags_rel 
           GROUP BY tags_rel.idea_id) t2 ON ideas.id = t2.idea_id` and add `*t2.cnt` where you need to put it in your own code

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the other answer with the subquery ultimately fixed my problem. It wasn't that I wanted `votes` * `tags` - I was getting that, I wanted the fix for it `=)`